# Maximum call stack size exceeded in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, scope

I write a extend method to achieve inheritance in javascript:

```
function Class() {}

Class.prototype.create = function () {
    var instance = new this();
    instance.init();
    return instance;
}


// extend method
Class.extend = Class.prototype.extend = function (props) {
    var SubClass = function () {};

    SubClass.prototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
    for (var name in props) {
        SubClass.prototype[name] = props[name];
    }
    SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

    if (this.prototype.init) {
        SubClass.prototype.callSuper = this.prototype.init; 
    }
    
    SubClass.extend = SubClass.prototype.extend;
    SubClass.create = SubClass.prototype.create;

    return SubClass;
}


// level 1 inheritance
var Human = Class.extend({
    init: function () {
    }
});

// level 2 inheritance
var Man = Human.extend({
    init: function () {
        this.callSuper();
    }
})

// level 3 inheritance
var American = Man.extend({
    init: function () {
        this.callSuper();
    }
})

// initilization 
American.create();
```

Then the develop tool report `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I think the `callSuper` method cause the problem, `callSuper` call `init`, and `init` call `callSuper`, both with the same context.

### But I don't know how to fixed it!

Can anyone could help me? How to set the correct context?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem but you can't access prototype using `this.prototype` but there is `__proto__`, but I think that not every browser support it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a scope problem. Here is the solution:

```
function Class() {}

Class.prototype.create = function () {
    var instance = new this();
    instance.init();
    return instance;
}


// extend method
Class.extend = Class.prototype.extend = function (props) {
    var SubClass = function () {},
        self = this;

    SubClass.prototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
    for (var name in props) {
        SubClass.prototype[name] = props[name];
    }
    SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

    if (this.prototype.init) {
        SubClass.prototype.callSuper = function() {
            self.prototype.init();
        }
    }

    SubClass.extend = SubClass.prototype.extend;
    SubClass.create = SubClass.prototype.create;

    return SubClass;
}


// level 1 inheritance
var Human = Class.extend({
    init: function () {
        console.log("Human");
    }
});

// level 2 inheritance
var Man = Human.extend({
    init: function () {
        console.log("Man");
        this.callSuper();
    }
})

// level 3 inheritance
var American = Man.extend({
    init: function () {
        console.log("American");
        this.callSuper();
    }
})

// initilization 
American.create();
```

The key moment is to wrap *init* method in a closure:

```
SubClass.prototype.callSuper = function() {
    self.prototype.init();
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle containing the solution http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/vGHUg/6/

Comment: Thank you very much. I have consider the scope problem, but I try a  closure solution: `(function (self) { SubClass.prototype.callSuper = self.prototype.init; })(this)`, but this doesn't work. What's the difference between your and my solution, doesn't they both create closure?

Comment: In your case you are actually calling the closure immediately. In my version the closure is passed and later called once you run *.callSuper()*.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what's the difference, is there any article or blog talk about the difference?